# comparing datetime and time produces a false result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using Mongoid and Chronic gem. Chronic produces a Time object, and Mongoid Date object produces a DateTime object. So in Mongoid, when i want to get today, I do something like this:

```
Lead.last.send('lead date') # => {DateTime}2015-03-30T00:00:00-04:00
```

In Chronic, when I parse today, I get this:

```
Chronic.parse('today') # => {Time}2015-03-30 23:00:00 -0400
```

And I compare the two with ==, it produces false, even though they are the same date. I need the following query to give a result, when 'lead date' refers to today:

```
Lead.where("lead date" => Chronic.parse('today'))
```

What options do I have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this code accurately replicate your issue?

```
require 'chronic'
require 'date'
text = "2015-03-30T00:00:00-04:00"
datetime = DateTime.parse(text)
time = Chronic.parse(text)
datetime == time
#=> false
```

Use the DateTime `#to_time` method, or the Time `#to_datetime` method:

```
datetime.to_time == time
#=> true

datetime == time.to_datetime
#=> true
```